# SSRS Scheduled report taking 1 hour off of time

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi, crm, microsoft-dynamics

I have an issue with a scheduled report. It's a Power BI report running on a schedule to pull information from on-premise a Dynamics 365 entity. Included in the report are several date/time fields and when the schedule runs it minuses 1 hour off of the time in these fields.

e.g. Data in CRM is 01/09/2020 00:00:00
Data on report is 31/08/2020 23:00:00

This **only** happens when the report is run via the subscription schedule, if the report is clicked in SSRS and run manually the fields show the correct time.

Any ideas?

Comment: When you are saying that you run manually, your mean that you run a report from your PC/laptop? If yes, then probably you have a different timezone on the server

Comment: I've checked the timezones on all servers involved. The database server, SSRS server and application server they're all the same and correct. When I say I can run it manually I mean by clicking the link from the SSRS server.